# Find same element in two array

Tags: java

I am trying to find the same element in two arrays, where the elements must have a maximum distance between them equal to k.

My two arrays (of different size and not sorted) A and B, k max distance.

This is what I have done, but I don't know where there is an error...

```java
for (int i = 0; i<A.length; i++){
    for(int j = i; j < k || j < B.length; j++)
        if(A[i] == B[j]){
            //Print on console
            System.out.println(B[i]);
            j = k;
        }
    }
}
```

For example:

```
A[3,7,5,9,10,15,16,1,6,2] 
B[4,8,5,13,1,17,2,11] 
k=6
```

The output should be `5 1 2`, but I don't know why, my program give me only `5` . Can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Try with System.out.println(B[j]); (B[i] may not exist each time) And replace for(int j = 0; j < k || j < B.length; j++)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    int startIndex = Math.max(i - k + 1, 0);
    int endIndex = Math.min(i + k, B.length);
    for (int j = startIndex; j < endIndex; j++){
        if (A[i] == B[j]) {
            System.out.println(B[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Uh, oh, not sure how you want the distance exactly, including the current element or excluding it. Also duplicates (in the same range) might be a special case to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you have a odd style to do that. Why you do `j = i`? If you do that, you do not iterate over all values.

That may help you. I tryed it out it should work:

```
    int[] a = {3,7,5,9,10,15,16,1,6,2};
    int[] b = {4,8,5,13,1,17,2,11};

    int k = 6;

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k || j < a.length; j++) {
            if (b[i] == a[j]) {
                System.out.println(a[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No wait i haven't to compare first element with all number to second just to first 6 element and then go on, secondo elemente with 2..7

Comment: @user1841492 I updated it! I used your array now ;) it should work with it.

Comment: you do not concern distance value k. There is no k in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are starting the j from i, so it will iterate only the items in B that are after the i element of A.

This may work

```
    for (int i = 0; i<A.length; i++){
        for(int j =Math.max(0, i-k) ; j < Math.min(B.length, i+k); j++){
            if(A[i] == B[j]){
                System.out.println(B[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Or:

```
    for (int i = 0; i<A.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < B.lenght; j++){
            if(A[i] == B[j] && Math.abs(i-j)<=k){
                System.out.println(B[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could fix your first example by replacing the first `if-else` with a `Math.min` and `Math.max` functions in the inner loop initializer.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik ,yep that seems better

Comment: This code have logic errors. First B[j] is compared, but B[i] is printed which may cause array out of bound exception. Setting j to k may cause infinite loop or array bound exception if second array length less than k.

Comment: @erencan ,oh you are right , I didnt saw what was inside the if ,I just copy pasted that part from the question's code ,silly me

Comment: If you use B.length-1 you have to use <= in the comparison of the for loop, otherwise you are not checking the last element of the array. (Also see my answer.)

Comment: @oddparity,oh another mistake... tnx for the note ,i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<A.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < B.length; j++)
                if(A[i] == B[j] && Math.abs(j-i)<k){
                    //Print on console
                    System.out.println(B[j]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Setting j to k may cause infinite loop or array bound exception if second array length less than k

Comment: don't get why you set j = k. looping j between i - k and i + k (within B bounds) would be more sensible.

Comment: That's my bad. I've copied user1841492's code, and make it work. During copy-paste, I forgot to remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. I checked, it works.

Your errors

- Your second loop initialization and stopping condition is wrong. It should start from i - k (if it is less than 0, then it should start 0) and stop when j exceeds i + k. Second loop should run between i - k and i + k in array bounds.
- You unconditionally set second loop variable to k which result unexpected behavior. Loop may go back a old value which result as infinite loop.
- You control B[j] value, but print B[i] value. Which may cause array out of bound exception.

int[] a = { 3, 7, 5, 9, 10, 15, 16, 1, 6, 2 };
  int[] b = { 4, 8, 5, 13, 1, 17, 2, 11 };
        int k = 6;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = ((i - k) < 0 ? 0 : i - k); j < i + k && j < b.length; j++) {

        if (a[i] == b[j]) {
            System.out.println(b[j]);
        }
    }  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what `k` is supposed to do, but your approach is `O(n^2)`, which is way too much.

Using sets, you can find the intersection quite easily :

```
Set<Integer> aSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
// Adding an element to a set is O(1), this addAll operation is therefore O(n)
Collections.addAll(aSet, A);

// This loop is also O(n), as contains is O(1)
for (int b : B) {
    if (aSet.contains(b)) {
        // this b int is in A and b
    }
}
```

Overall, this approach is `O(n)`

### Edit

As for `k`, my understanding in what you are doing is that you are only testing that `j < k`, which explains why only 5 comes out. you need to test the distance between i and j which is tested by

```
Math.abs(j-i) < k
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getSameItems(aList, bList):
    a_max = aList[0]
    b_max = bList[0]
    for item in aList:
        if item > a_max: a_max = item
    for item in bList:
        if item > b_max: b_max = item
    aList_counting = [0] * (a_max + 1)
    bList_counting = [0] * (b_max + 1)

    for item in aList: aList_counting[item] += 1
    for item in bList: bList_counting[item] += 1
    min_item = a_max if a_max < b_max else b_max
    sameList = []
    for i in range(min_item + 1):
        if aList_counting[i] > 0 and bList_counting[i] > 0:
            sameList.append(i)
    return sameList
aList = [1, 7, 2, 2, 8]
bList = [1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 9, 2, 8]
print getSameItems(aList, bList)
[1, 2, 7, 8]
```

The above code is used in the python language,I am Chinese,so my english is poor，and cannot provide rich code annotations,sorry..I suggest that you can use [counting sorting](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/) ideas,I hope it will help you!